# How do I get python to display xbar? A line over the letter x

Tags: python, text, matplotlib, notation

I've been looking at math notation and different packages but have yet to find anything that lets me print xbar (the average x).

I am hoping to use xbar as a label in matplotlib.

Any suggestions?

Thank you. Cheers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to use x bar as a label in matplotlib, you can do it like this:

```
plt.ylabel(r'$\bar{x}$')
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it! Also note `\overline{xyz}` for multiple characters and `\mathregular{\bar{x}}` if you want it to use the non-math font so it appears seamless with other text.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using jupyter you can simply do this for one letter (x):

```
$\bar x$   

#or for a string   
$\overline {xyzabc}$   

#note that one $ will give you an inline output and $$...$$ would start  
#a new line after your output
```